# same subscript code, when building it with two Separate lines it's working fine, when building it with one line of code, im getting an error , why?

Tags: swift, xcode, subscript

I've add two pictures of my code , that explain both Scenarios
at the first scenario the subscript work exactly like its supposed to work, with Two lines of code

at the secound scenario , the code should evaluate same as the two line, but im getting an error for some reason

can you help me figure out WHY?

working image :[working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGbsq.png)

error image : [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGVXX.png)

full code:

```
class SomeClass {

    var dic = Dictionary<String,(()->String) -> String>()

    subscript(_ s:String) -> (()->String) -> String {

        get{
            return dic[s]!
        }set{
            dic[s] = newValue
        }


    }


}


func createClass(_ s:String) -> SomeClass {

    func foo(_ str:()->String) ->String {
        return str() + " AND " + "Two"
    }
    let sc = SomeClass()
    sc["0"] = foo

    return sc

}


// WORKING TWO LINES

let someClass  = createClass("someStr")["0"]
let str = someClass{"One"} // everything work fine, no errors // prints 'One AND Two'



// ERROR ONE LINE

let str  = createClass("someStr")["0"]{"One"}



// WHY?
```

Comment: tnx for the quick response . YES its working that way, but I need to figure out why   its not evaluate as it supposed to , the compiler telling me that im putting some kind of a closure in the [ ] , and im not, as you can see I the picture . is it some kind of compiler problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example:

```
let str = createClass("someStr")["0"]{"One"}
```

is using *trailing closure syntax*.

*Trailing closure syntax* works by including the trailing closure as an additional parameter to a function call.  Subscripting an array is really a function call under the hood (to a function called `subscript`), and Swift is trying to pass that closure as a second parameter to the subscripting call, which is what the error is explaining:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'SomeClass' with an argument of type '(String, () -> String)'.

In other words, you can't pass both `"0"` and the closure `{"One"}` to the subscripting function.

---

There are at least 3 ways to fix this and still put it on one line:

**Option 1:  Use an explicit call to pass the closure instead of using *trailing closure syntax***

Wrap the closure in `()` to make the call explicit:

```
let str1 = createClass("someStr")["0"]({"One"})
print(str1)
```

**Option 2:  Wrap the `createClass("someStr")["0"]` in parentheses**

That lets Swift know the subscripting only gets `"0"` as a parameter and allows trailing closure syntax to work as expected:

```
let str2 = (createClass("someStr")["0"]){"One"}
print(str2)
```

**Option 3:  Add `.self` to the result before the trailing closure syntax:**

That again finishes the subscripting call and avoids the confusion.

```
let str3 = createClass("someStr")["0"].self {"One"}
print(str3)
```

Personally, I would choose **Option 1**, because *trailing closure syntax* is **unnecessary** syntactic sugar that clearly is not working here.

---

### Solving the Challenge

In the comments I asked:

> I agree that the trailing closure syntax is most likely a bug that they could fix, but what I don't understand is why you insist on using trailing closure syntax here. What is so objectionable about wrapping the closure in () to make the call explicit even if it is just to work around a bug in Swift?

You replied:

> the reason for the insisting is that I'm trying to solve a challenge.
>   actually , this function that return a closure is only one side of it
>   it goes like this
>
> ```
> func Challenge() {
>     // Do not edit below this line
>      XCTAssertEqual(foo("str1")["str2"]{ "654321" }, "123456")
>  }
> ```

We've already established that *trailing closure syntax* is pairing the final closure with the indexing operation, so the trick is to design a class that takes a closure with its indexing operation:

```
class SomeClass {
    subscript(_ s: String, closure: () -> String) -> String {
        return String(closure().reversed())
    }
}

func foo(_ str: String) -> SomeClass {
    return SomeClass()
}

func Challenge() {
    // Do not edit below this line
    XCTAssertEqual(foo("str1")["str2"]{ "654321" }, "123456")
}
```

Comment: @yehudshe, did this answer your question?

Comment: it did make me understand more the problem of that syntax . so yes , but I'm still looking for a solution for this syntax to work as it he's, meaning that a closure that takes a `String` and returning  a `String`,   `(String)->String`  will some how evaluate from that syntax of subscription (it could be anything, a custom class, a `Dictionary<String,(String,(String)->String )` ) . tnx for your time in helping solving/understanding it.

Comment: I agree that the trailing closure syntax is most likely a bug that they could fix, but what I don't understand is why you insist on using trailing closure syntax here.  What is so objectionable about wrapping the closure in `()` to make the call explicit even if it is just to work around a bug in Swift?

Comment: the reason for the insisting is that I'm trying to solve a challenge. actually , this function that return a closure is only one side of it . it goes like this  ` func Challenge() {
        // Do not edit below this line
        XCTAssertEqual(foo("str1")["str2"]{ "654321" }, "123456")
    } `

Comment: This might work for your challenge: `func foo(_ str: String) -> [String : Any] { return ["str2": "123456"] }` then `foo("str1")["str2"]{ "654321" }` will indeed return `"123456"`.  The only potential problem is that it will be `Any` and not `String`.

Comment: yes is causes a problem because `Any`  don't conform to  'Equatable' protocol , which is needed for the `XCTAssertEqual` function to work, nice try though.

Comment: AMAZING!, thank you, I thought so "to give the compiler  what he was asking for" but didn't know how to implement it . so you can actually  subscript this  'thing' meaning a 'String, and A closure' together  that he will return a String , didn't think it was possible.  Wow. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put parentheses around `createClass("someStr")["0"]`, because it's trying to evaluate `["0"]{"One"}` *before* it evaluates `createClass("someStr")` with a subscript. And even when you make this change, you'll get a compilation error because you declared the variable `str` twice.

Sometimes it's just easier (not to mention clearer) to have two separate statements, instead of trying to be clever.

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

class SomeClass {
    var dic = Dictionary<String,(()->String) -> String>()
    subscript(_ s:String) -> (()->String) -> String {
        get{
            return dic[s]!
        }set{
            dic[s] = newValue
        }
    }
}
func createClass(_ s:String) -> SomeClass {
    func foo(_ str:()->String) ->String {
        return str() + " AND " + "Two"
    }
    let sc = SomeClass()
    sc["0"] = foo
    return sc
}

str = (createClass("someStr")["0"]){"One"}
print(str) // One AND Two
```

Comment: Yeah this must be new behavior. Worked fine in earlier version of Xcode.

Comment: Bizarre. Why would they change the order of operator precedence?

Comment: tnx , now can I force the compiler some how to evaluate the line from left to right?, so the line will work as it is? .

Comment: The parentheses ARE what force the compiler to evaluate the line from left to right. It's still sloppy, though; just use two lines. You'll thank yourself for it when you have to debug that code again someday.

Comment: Trailing closure parsing has always been a bit iffy. There are lots of situations where parens are needed.

Comment: just to be clearer , im trying to get this code to work just as it is, I don't want to add any thing to it, its some kind of a challenge . this code should have been complained from left to right, now you in-light me that the compiler evaluate first the  ["0"]{"One"} and after the createClass("someStr") , now our friend matt infer us that its a new behaviour, SO , if that's a new  behaviour , can you reverse it ? . my main target is that line will stay the same , and will compile as in the Two lIne of Code . tnx :)

Comment: So instead of using two lines, or using parentheses on one line, your preferred approach is to change how the _compiler_ works? I suppose that you could always build the latest Swift LLDB compiler by hand and set it as a custom toolchain in Xcode, but I hope, _hope_ that's not what you're asking for. Its current lack of readability is enough of a challenge in itself.