# swift 5.1 evaluate a closure in the wrong way

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having an issue with evaluation of one line of code
if i break it down to two lines, it's working , but in one line of code, it's just evaluate in a 'new' to a 'wrong' way.

my main reason for asking this question, is not to solve it, I know I can use parenthesis to solve it, and break it to Two line, but don't want to solve it, I just want to know why its evaluated like this , and if there's a solution for this : some setting to patch , in Order THAT it will work in ONE LINE OF CODE :

Heres the code that working in Two lines

[image: working code]

Heres the code that trying to do the same thing, but rise an error as you can see:

[image: error code]

full code of both working and not working :

```
class ClosuresStack {

var dic = Dictionary<String,(()->String)->String >()

subscript(_ str:String)-> (()->String)->String {
get {
return dic[str]!

}
set {
dic[str] = newValue
}

}


}

func createClosuresStak() -> ClosuresStack {

   let cs =  ClosuresStack()
    func takesAClosureReturnA_string(_ closure:()->String) ->String {
        return closure() + " Two"
    }

    cs["C"] = takesAClosureReturnA_string

    return cs
}

let c = createClosuresStak()["C"]
let str = c{"One"}
print(str)  // print:  One Two



let c = createClosuresStak()["C"]{"One"} // error -->
```

now, I want to somehow understand how to change it that it will work in ONE LINE OF CODE : meaning that the evaluation of '`createClosuresStak()["C"]{"One"}`' will create a closure after ["C"] , and then from  that point writing  the  `{"One"}`
will make it a full evaluate of the line :

```
let c = createClosuresStak()["C"]{"One"}
```

making 'c' a String

if that's not possible, I need to know it Too , tnx :)

***UPDATE***

tnx for the comments , its help me understand the problem more clearly :

1) im understanding that the `createClosuresStak()["C"]{"One"}` 
acutely  trying to add the string 'One' as another parameter to the sub script , and there for the error from the compiler was that is cannot subscript (String,()->String} , 'C' as the string inside the [] , and the other parameter `{"One"}` -> BUT , isn't that some kind of a bug?, been that i'm using [] ,Cleary the compiler need to 'understand' that I want to subscript a String, also by power of inferring that swift has,

2) now I'm still trying to get that syntax to work as it is so I try to change some things, in order to get it to work :

so I created a function that take a string, and return a dictionary of type : `Dictionary<String,()->String>`, and then trying so subscript it 
and the compiler don't rise an error that way :

```
func closuresDictionary(_ s:String) -> Dictionary<String,()->String> {

    var dic = Dictionary<String,()->String>()
    func foo()->String {
        return s + " Two"
    }
    dic["C"] = foo
    return dic
}




let c = closuresDictionary("One")["C"]{ "SomeString" }
```

c is now a closure of type `()->String` which does noting with string that I put inside, so the syntax works, but the outcome is not doing anything.

when im changing the return type of the dictionary to a different closure : `(String)->String` instead of  `()->String` , im getting the same old error, that I'm trying to subscript a `(String,(String)->String)`

and I need a function that will take the string inside the {} , and create something from it meaning that I need to subscript to return a closure of `(String)->String`

its seems like there's no way to do that

im adding two more pictures of my last trying in order to get this line of code in current syntax to work

the wanted syntax working but the outcome is not an outcome not doing any thing with the string inside the {}:

[image: the wanted syntax working but the outcome is not an outcome not doing any thing with the string inside the {}]

same error, by changing the function to `(String)->String`

[image: same error, by changing the function to (String)->String]

Comment: Isn't that what you asked in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59792312/1187415?

Comment: As pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59792506/1187415 you can make it compile in one line by adding extra parentheses:  `createClass("someStr")["0"]` – I deleted my answer because I was not convinced about my explanation anymore.

Comment: I'm not persuaded that this is not identical to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59792312/1187415. Persuade me. We've established that in older versions of Swift your one-line syntax worked and that now it requires parentheses or multiple lines. How is this question different? You want to make it work in one line, add the parentheses. The end.

Comment: @MartinR As I pointed out in the duplicate earlier question, the proposed syntax used to work. I don't know when the parsing changed.

Comment: @matt: I don't know either.  But I just verified that it does *not* compile in Xcode 9.4.1 (Swift 4.1).

Comment: @MartinR It compiles in Xcode 9.2. Our binary search is working!

Comment: @matt: Strange – it does not compile in my Xcode 9.2.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, great, now it doesn't compile in mine either. But it must have when I posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/59792425/341994 so who knows what's going on. Now I'm glad I deleted it.

Comment: in the last example, the returning value is value of dictionary for key /Optional function with String parameter/ you have to call it as  closuresDictionary("One")["C"]?("SomeString") ?? "" which gives you the string

Comment: yes it should return an optional from the dictionary , and I can also unwrap it like so `let c = closuresDictionary("One")["C"]!{"d"}` . BUT , as you can see in the first example , when the dictionary should return a `() ->String` it did evaluate a None Optional closure. so that syntax did evaluate to 'something' and even not an optional something although its should have been an optional, but the { } , some how make it to return an None Optional for some reason.

Comment: In the first example, trailing closure syntax is actually performing this operation: `let c = closureDictionary("One")["C", default: { "d" }]`.  By using the `default:` version of the dictionary indexing, a non-optional is always returned.  If the key isn't present, the `default:` value is used.  So, your `{ "d" }` is getting consumed by the dictionary lookup and isn't used.  Again, trailing closure syntax is the culprit, and it found a version of `[]` that actually takes a closure as the second argument and used it.

Answer (score 2):

Your example:

```
let c = createClosuresStak()["C"]{"One"}
```

is using *trailing closure syntax*.

*Trailing closure syntax* works by including the trailing closure as an additional parameter to a function call.  Subscripting an array is really a function call under the hood (to a function called `subscript`), and Swift is trying to pass that closure as a second parameter to the subscripting call, which is what the error is explaining:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'ClosuresStack' with an argument of type '(String, () -> String)'.

In other words, you can't pass both `"C"` and the closure `{"One"}` to the subscripting function.

---

There are at least 3 ways to fix this and still put it on one line:

**Option 1:  Use an explicit call to pass the closure instead of using *trailing closure syntax***

Wrap the closure in `()` to make the call explicit:

```
let c1 = createClosuresStak()["C"]({"One"})
print(c1)
```

**Option 2:  Wrap the `createClosureStak()["C"]` in parentheses**

That lets Swift know the subscripting only gets `"C"` as a parameter and allows trailing closure syntax to work as expected:

```
let c2 = (createClosuresStak()["C"]){"One"}
print(c2)
```

**Option 3:  Add `.self` to the result before the trailing closure syntax:**

That again finishes the subscripting call and avoids the confusion.

```
let c3 = createClosuresStak()["C"].self {"One"}
print(c3)
```

Personally, I would choose option one, because *trailing closure syntax* is unnecessary syntactic sugar that clearly is not working here.

Comment: Does that also explain why `foo(){ print($0) }` in my deleted answer does not compile?

Comment: @MartinR, yes.  The trailing closure syntax is trying to add `{ print($0) }` to the call of `foo`, but `foo` takes no arguments.  The same 3 fixes work: `foo()( { print($0) })`, `(foo()) { print($0) }`, and `foo().self { print($0) }`.

Comment: @vacawama This is brilliant but in my view it should be the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/59792312/1187415 rather than this question, which is a mere repetition / duplicate.

Comment: @matt, I have put the answer there.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks, that's a great outcome.

Comment: @matt, you might be interested in what the OP was really asking and where this ended up going.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814139/1630618) on the previous question.

Comment: @MartinR, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814139/1630618) on the previous question to see what the OP was really asking and where this ended up going.